# What is the difference between "determining" and "analysing"

Tags: meaning, differences

Do "determining" and "analysing" have different meanings?

What is the difference between "determining" and "analysing"?

- [...] while analysing current price characteristics.
- [...] while determining current price characteristics.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you?  When you *analyze* something, you study its *known* characteristics.  When you *determine* something you figure out or solve for something *unknown*

Comment: Really? Really ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing is very general. It may simply lead to a greater understanding with no specific output or outcome. If you analyze something you might produce a report.

Determining means evaluating something and producing some conclusive outcome, like one of several options, or a definitive list of characteristics.